# Can I install VS Studio Express with and after installing Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio

Or there will be some conflicts ?

Comment: What release year of visual studio express?

Comment: I have installed VS Express 2010 Beta 2 without any conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It they are different versions (i.e. 2005, 2008, 2010) there shouldn't be a problem.

If you try the same version (2008 express with 2008 pro), this is also supported.

What will not work is trying Standard with Pro (for example).

See the answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233123/can-several-suites-of-the-same-version-of-visual-studio-be-installed-side-by-side) SO question (Can several suites of the same version of Visual Studio be installed Side by Side ?).

Comment: @Oded, there is a big difference between trying to install Pro and Standard of the same version on one machine and installing Pro and Express.  Combining Pro and Standard is not a supported scenario while installing Express and Pro is

Comment: @JaredPar - thanks for the info. Answer updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a supported scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but I wouldn't recommend it. The biggest issue you will run into is that it will change the file associations for the solution and project files so they open in VS2008 Express rather then VS2008 by default when you double-click the file in Explorer. Other than that, I experienced no other issues when I had both installed. (I also installed VS2008 Express after VS2008.)