# Can I install two visual studio with the same version in the same computer?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Can I install Visual Studio 2012 professional and Visual Studio 2012 for desktop express in the same computer?

Actually, I have Visual Studio 2012 professional installed on my computer but it has an education license.

I need Visual Studio 2012 express for sell applications.

Comment: Why would you use an old version of Express?

Comment: Try it. I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/233123/103167) says that, at least for older versions, the answer is yes.

Comment: It will work, just be aware if you have processed any updates to the first version that you added you will have to install them again because some of the common files will be overwritten with the original files when you install the other version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can install different editions of the same version of Visual Studio side-by-side. I do it all the time.